# Keep command button visible while scrolling down worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there anyway to keep a command button visible and while you are scolling down a long worksheet, you can still see the button scroll with your worksheet? I know there is the freeze pane but I would prefer something else if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. You mentioned the freeze pane option. another way is to use a command in a custom ribbon group. If you want something floating on sheet, you could create a floating user form with the button(s). Debra Dahlgliesh has a [tutorial for a floating form](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2016/01/14/excel-macro-buttons-on-floating-form/) on the Contextures.com site.

Comment: Could the downvoter please elaborate?

Comment: is there a way to only show that floating user form on the active workbook/worksheet it was created on. Seems like it would float on any excel file opened which I do not want to happen.